# Get items from a tree structure ( N number of nested lists) using LINQ and recursion - c#

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

I have an object of type Class1. Class1 has the following properties: member(int), parent(Class1), lstMembers(of Class1).

For example:

Object A has no parent (parent == null). In the list of object A, we have two objects A1 and A2 of type Class1 of course. In the list of object A1, we have an object A11. In the list of object A2, we have an object A21.

```
A -> A1, A2
A1 -> A11
A2 -> A21
```

So there are three levels in the tree. The number of levels is known. I want to get the value of the property Member for each object in the tree using LINQ and recursion. I cannot seem to find a solution for this. Note that I cannot remove an object in the list for some particular reason. I did find a solution which included removing objects from the nested lists (recursion solution).

sample code with removing objects from the list:

```
static void GetMembers(Class1 child, Class1 parent, ref List<int> lstMember)
    {
        // last level
        if (child.lstC.Count == 0)
        {
            lstMember.Add(child.member);
            Console.WriteLine(child.member + " added " + child.name);
            // remove all from last level
            if (parent != null)
            {
                parent.lstC.Remove(child);
                if (parent.lstC.Count != 0)
                    GetMembers(parent.lstC.First(), parent, ref lstMember);
            }
        }
        // group level
        else
        {
            GetMembers(child.lstC.First(), child, ref lstMember);

            if (parent != null && parent.lstC.Count != 0)
            {
                GetMembers(parent.lstC.First(), parent, ref lstMember);
            }
            else
            {
                GetMembers(child, null, ref lstMember);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to get the items without removing the items using LINQ

Answer (score 0):

I've made two extension methods for you.
The first will search to test is an item is in the tree.

*Note: The reason you can't remove from a list is because it can't be altered while being enumerated.  This is a safety of collections.  The answer is to duplicate the list or collection.  I've done this using `ToList()` in the removal code examples I've provided.  Notice I don't need to so that in the searching versions since there are no alterations.*

You supply the way to search.
You supply the way to access the nested types.

Here's an example of searching for an item in the tree:

```
var isInTree = dataList.FoundInTree(searchItem: item => item.Id == 6,
                                    nestedItems: item => item.NestedData);
```

Here's an example of removing an item from the tree:

```
var removedFromTree = dataList.RemoveFirstFromTree(searchItem: item => item.Id == 6,
                                                   nestedItems: item => item.NestedData);
```

I've included overloads / variations of these methods to allow for searching / removing of multiple items of the same:

```
var isInTree = dataList.FoundInTree(searchItem: item => item.Id == 6,
                                    nestedItems: item => item.NestedData,
                                    out int foundCount);

var removedFromTree = dataList.RemoveAllFromTree(searchItem: item => item.Id == 6,
                                                 nestedItems: item => item.NestedData,
                                                 out int removedCount);
```

I've also included a sample application that mocks data showing how this can be used but first here are the extension methods:

**Extension Methods (Here is your answer in code)**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool FoundInTree<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> searchItem, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> nestedItems)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (searchItem.Invoke(item)) return true;
            if (nestedItems.Invoke(item).FoundInTree(searchItem, nestedItems)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool RemoveFirstFromTree<T>(this ICollection<T> items, Func<T, bool> searchItem, Func<T, ICollection<T>> nestedItems)
    {
        foreach (var item in items.ToList())
        {
            if (searchItem.Invoke(item))
            {
                items.Remove(item);
                return true;
            }
            if (nestedItems.Invoke(item).RemoveFirstFromTree(searchItem, nestedItems))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool FoundInTree<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> searchItem, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> nestedItems, out int count)
    {
        count = 0;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (searchItem.Invoke(item)) count++;
            if (nestedItems.Invoke(item).FoundInTree(searchItem, nestedItems, out int nestedCount)) count += nestedCount;
        }
        return count > 0;
    }

    public static bool RemoveAllFromTree<T>(this ICollection<T> items, Func<T, bool> searchItem, Func<T, ICollection<T>> nestedItems, out int count)
    {
        var isAnyRemoved = false;
        count = 0;
        foreach (var item in items.ToList())
        {
            if (searchItem.Invoke(item))
            {
                items.Remove(item);
                isAnyRemoved = true;
                count++;
            }
            if (nestedItems.Invoke(item).RemoveAllFromTree(searchItem, nestedItems, out int nestedCount))
            {
                isAnyRemoved = true;
                count += nestedCount;
            }
        }
        return isAnyRemoved;
    }
}
```

Now here's the complete console app (including extension methods).  You can copy and paste this as is and play with it however you want.

**Console App**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
namespace Question_Answer_Console_App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dataList = GetMockData();

            var isInTree = dataList.FoundInTree(searchItem: item => item.Id == 6,
                                                nestedItems: item => item.NestedData,
                                                out int foundCount);

            if (isInTree)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Found {foundCount} items in the tree.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("None found in the tree.");
            }

            var removedFromTree = dataList.RemoveAllFromTree(searchItem: item => item.Id == 6,
                                                             nestedItems: item => item.NestedData,
                                                             out int removedCount);

            if (removedFromTree)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Removed {removedCount} items from the tree.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"No items removed from the tree.");
            }

            isInTree = dataList.FoundInTree(searchItem: item => item.Id == 6,
                                           nestedItems: (item) => item.NestedData);

            if (isInTree)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Found {foundCount} items in the tree.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("None found in the tree.");
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static List<Data<int>> GetMockData()
        {
            var dataList = new List<Data<int>>();

            for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                dataList.Add(getData(i));
            }

            return dataList;

            Data<int> getData(int count)
            {
                var data = new Data<int>
                {
                    Id = count
                };

                for (var j = count; j > 0; j--)
                {
                    var innerData = new Data<int>
                    {
                        Id = j
                    };

                    innerData.NestedData.Add(getData(--j));
                    data.NestedData.Add(innerData);
                }

                return data;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Data<T>
    {
        public T Id { get; set; }
        public List<Data<T>> NestedData { get; set; } = new List<Data<T>>();
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static bool FoundInTree<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> searchItem, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> nestedItems)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (searchItem.Invoke(item)) return true;
                if (nestedItems.Invoke(item).FoundInTree(searchItem, nestedItems)) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static bool RemoveFirstFromTree<T>(this ICollection<T> items, Func<T, bool> searchItem, Func<T, ICollection<T>> nestedItems)
        {
            foreach (var item in items.ToList())
            {
                if (searchItem.Invoke(item))
                {
                    items.Remove(item);
                    return true;
                }
                if (nestedItems.Invoke(item).RemoveFirstFromTree(searchItem, nestedItems))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static bool FoundInTree<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> searchItem, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> nestedItems, out int count)
        {
            count = 0;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (searchItem.Invoke(item)) count++;
                if (nestedItems.Invoke(item).FoundInTree(searchItem, nestedItems, out int nestedCount)) count += nestedCount;
            }
            return count > 0;
        }

        public static bool RemoveAllFromTree<T>(this ICollection<T> items, Func<T, bool> searchItem, Func<T, ICollection<T>> nestedItems, out int count)
        {
            var isAnyRemoved = false;
            count = 0;
            foreach (var item in items.ToList())
            {
                if (searchItem.Invoke(item))
                {
                    items.Remove(item);
                    isAnyRemoved = true;
                    count++;
                }
                if (nestedItems.Invoke(item).RemoveAllFromTree(searchItem, nestedItems, out int nestedCount))
                {
                    isAnyRemoved = true;
                    count += nestedCount;
                }
            }
            return isAnyRemoved;
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> //OUTPUTS
> //Found 2 items in the tree.
> //Removed 2 items from the tree.
> //None found in the tree.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
class Class1
{
    public Class1(string Name)
    {
        lstC = new List<Class1>();
        this.name = Name;
    }
    public List<Class1> lstC { get; set; }

    public string name { get; }
    public int member { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 par = new Class1("A") { member = 4 };
        Class1 c1 = new Class1("A1") { member = 54};
        Class1 c2 = new Class1("A2") { member = 5 };
        par.lstC.Add(c1);
        par.lstC.Add(c2);
        Class1 c11 = new Class1("A11") { member = 39 };
        c1.lstC.Add(c11);
        Class1 c21 = new Class1("A21") { member = 67 };
        c2.lstC.Add(c21);

        List<int> result = new List<int>();

        GetMembers(par, ref result);
    }

    static void GetMembers(Class1 parent, ref List<int> lstMember)
    {
        lstMember.Add(parent.member);

        foreach (var child in parent.lstC)
        {
            GetMembers(child, ref lstMember);
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with, hopefully at the right level of abstraction

```
void Main()
{
    var dataStructure = Init_DataStructure();

    List<int> members = GetMembers(dataStructure).ToList();
}

IEnumerable<int> GetMembers(Class1 input)
{
    yield return input.Member;

    foreach (var subMember in input.MemberList.SelectMany(c => GetMembers(c)))
        yield return subMember;
}

Class1 Init_DataStructure()
{
    Class1
        a1 = new Class1
        {
            Id = "A1",
            Member = 1,
            MemberList = new Collection<Class1>()
        },
        a11 = new Class1
        {
            Id = "A11",
            Member = 2,
            Parent = a1
        };
    a1.MemberList.Add(a11);

    Class1
        a2 = new Class1
        {
            Id = "A2",
            Member = 3,
            MemberList = new Collection<Class1>()
        },
        a21 = new Class1
        {
            Id = "A21",
            Member = 4,
            Parent = a2
        };
    a2.MemberList.Add(a21);

    return new Class1
    {
        Id = "A",
        Member = 0,
        MemberList = new Collection<Class1> { a1, a2 }
    };
}

class Class1
{
    public Class1() => MemberList = new Collection<Class1>();

    public Class1 Parent { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Member { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Class1> MemberList { get; set; }
}
```